# MySQL combining two properly outputting queries into a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

I'm quite new to mySQL and don't really understand what I need to do to get the desired outcome. The query I created gives the correct n_levels and n_events when the LEFT JOIN statements are implemented independently, but I don't know how to properly combine them into a single query. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the expected output:

```
+-----------+--------+---------+----------+----------+
| SwimmerId | FName  | LName   | n_levels | n_events |
+-----------+--------+---------+----------+----------+
|         1 | Bobby  | Khan    |        3 |        6 |
|         2 | Billy  | Khan    |        2 |        4 |
|         3 | Nina   | Khan    |        2 |        5 |
|         4 | Clara  | Johnson |        3 |        4 |
|         5 | Philip | Johnson |        2 |        4 |
|         6 | Joe    | Fen     |        2 |        1 |
+-----------+--------+---------+----------+----------+
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.SwimmerId, s.FName, s.LName, COUNT(lh.SwimmerId) AS 'n_levels', COUNT(p.SwimmerId) AS 'n_events'
FROM swimmer AS s LEFT JOIN levelhistory AS lh ON (s.SwimmerId = lh.SwimmerId),
     swimmer AS s2 LEFT JOIN participation AS p ON (s2.SwimmerId = p.SwimmerId)
GROUP BY s.SwimmerId
ORDER BY s.SwimmerId;
```

This is my output:

```
+-----------+--------+---------+----------+----------+
| SwimmerId | FName  | LName   | n_levels | n_events |
+-----------+--------+---------+----------+----------+
|         1 | Bobby  | Khan    |       72 |       72 |
|         2 | Billy  | Khan    |       48 |       48 |
|         3 | Nina   | Khan    |       48 |       48 |
|         4 | Clara  | Johnson |       72 |       72 |
|         5 | Philip | Johnson |       48 |       48 |
|         6 | Joe    | Fen     |       48 |       48 |
+-----------+--------+---------+----------+----------+
```

This query gives the proper value for n_levels:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.SwimmerId, s.FName, s.LName, COUNT(lh.SwimmerId) AS 'n_levels'
FROM swimmer AS s LEFT JOIN levelhistory AS lh ON (s.SwimmerId = lh.SwimmerId)
GROUP BY s.SwimmerId
ORDER BY s.SwimmerId;
```

This query gives the proper value for n_events:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.SwimmerId, s.FName, s.LName, COUNT(p.SwimmerId) AS 'n_events'
FROM swimmer AS s LEFT JOIN participation AS p ON (s.SwimmerId = p.SwimmerId)
GROUP BY s.SwimmerId
ORDER BY s.SwimmerId;
```

As I said earlier, when I separate the query into two separate queries (just using one of the left joins each query) it gives the expected output, but when I add the second query it seems to be multiplying the correct value of n_levels by the number of rows which exists in participation. Pretty much everything I've tried is outputting the same values into the n_levels and n_events output. I feel like i'm really close to the solution since I am able to find the correct outputs individually, but I don't really know why the query I created combining them is giving the incorrect outputs, and I don't know where to go next.

I have attached an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGwpH.png) of the tables from the database if they're necessary, though I'm not sure they are. Thank you for any help you are able to provide!

Comment: Use ANSI JOIN for all the joins, especially don't mix `LEFT JOIN` and cross products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is joins vs outer aggregation; there are several matches in each join, so rows end up counted multiple times.

A typical solution is aggregate in subqueries, *then* join the results:

```
SELECT s.SwimmerId, s.FName, s.LName, lh.n_levels, p.n_events
FROM swimmer AS s 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SwimmerId, COUNT(*) AS n_levels FROM levelhistory  GROUP BY SwimmerId) lh 
    ON lh.SwimmerId = s.SwimmerId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SwimmerId, COUNT(*) as n_events FROM participation GROUP BY SwimmerId) p  
    ON p.SwimmerId = s.SwimmerId
ORDER BY s.SwimmerId;
```

Note that `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` together do not really make sense (both atually mean aggregation). Also, it is a good practice to enumerate *all* non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause - although MySQL might allow otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this helps a lot!